# what is the best mining intenisty to use for certain grahpichs cards?

Tags: litecoin, cgminer, mining-pools, gpu

I use cgminer and I have a zotac nvidia geforce gtx 680 graphics card, what is the best intensity to use.

Answer (score 1):

I would not bother using a nvidia graphic card but the choice is yours from experience they run way to hot and don't produce enough power especially at current difficulty. Anyway take a look at this list https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison it lists a lot of best settings as well as gives you an idea if your card is hitting the hashing rate that it should be.

Comment: I know amd cards are much better, but for now what do you think i should put the intensity on?

Comment: Their is no hard and fast rule as their are to many GPU's and variations of each GPU for a list to be made with every exact setting. I would start with 8 and compare the hash rate to the hash rate listed on the link about if you are getting between 110 and 120kh your intensity is fine. You can try going up by one and seeing if it helps after that making sure that you are not getting hardware errors if you are not and the hash improves try going up again until its you see hardware errors or your hash is not what you expect. Playing with cgminer is more of an art than a science.